# Visual C# 2008 Express doesn't give me any options for break points besides creating/deleting them

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-express

I'm not sure why this is, but all I get is a 'create breakpoint' and 'delete breakpoint'. There is no option for a 'when hit' or something else like that.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality is not provided in the Express edition of Visual Studio. You can have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure where BP info is stored, but this did the trick for me (C# 2010 Express):

- close the IDE
- delete the *.vshost.exe (see EXE/DLL output folder)
- delete the *.SUO file
- now re-open the IDE and load the project again.

**Notes:**

- The *.vshost.exe might need to be terminated the hard way before you can delete it.
- Deleting the *.SUO file also takes away some of the IDE project group settings, such as files opened, project tree folding, etc.